# Subscribe Input Box Right Padding

Tags: magento, alignment, footer, subscribe, inputbox

please help! I am new to HTML/CSS, currently working on my Magento website.  After reinstalling Magento 2.1.7 have found that my subscription box is no longer aligned with the footer. I have tried editing /app/design/frontend/Infortis/base/Magento_Newsletter/web/css/source/module.less but nothing changes. 
here is how it looks like:
[Subscribe Footer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/szN3D.png)

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Can you please share your demo link?

Comment: https://www.krafersparadise.sg thanks!

Comment: Go to "pub/static/version1506919457/frontend/Infortis/ultimo/en_GB/css/styles-l.css" find ".block.newsletter .field .control" class change width 300% to 100%.

Comment: .block.newsletter .field .control {
  width: 100%;
}